# ActiveRecord Reputation System - Only displaying karma for one vote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a pretty simple reputation system defined.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_reputation :votes, :source => :user, :aggregated_by => :sum

  def upvote(user)
    self.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, 1, user)
  end

  def downvote(user)
    self.add_or_update_evaluation(:votes, -1, user)
  end

  def score
    self.reputation_for(:score).to_i
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_reputation :karma, 
    :source => [:reputation => :votes, :of => :posts, :weight => 10],
    :aggregated_by => :sum

 def karma
    self.reputation_for(:karma).to_i
  end
end
```

For the most part it works. Users are able to change their votes, upvote or downvote, and score is returned correctly for the posts.

However, when I get a user's karma in the case one of their posts has 2 upvotes, I would expect their karma to be 20, but 10 is returned. Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Which gem you are using? This reputation and karma thing.

Comment: @MurifoX DVG is using this: https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system

Comment: @DVG Never used this gem, but can't see anything wrong off the bat. Do you want to post the controller code that handles the upvote?

Comment: Do you have any specs for this? IMO adding some unit tests would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Post` model also needs a `:source_of` so it knows which other reputations refer to it, so they can be updated:

```
has_reputation :votes,
  :source => :user,
  :aggregated_by => :sum,
  :source_of => {:reputation => :karma, :of => :user}
```

Note:

If the `karma` is out of sync with the `votes`, you can find & delete the `karma` records for that user, and they'll be regenerated the next time you access them.

```
user.reputations.where(reputation_name: 'karma')
```

Some other suggested tweaks:

- you should define `belongs_to :user` in `Post`
- you should define `has_many :posts` in `User`
- your `score` method needs to pass the `:votes` symbol instead of `:score`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much. As to your other notes, I just omitted most of that stuff for brevity, but thanks very much for pointing it out regardless. Have 110 reputation :)

Comment: Ooops, I can't award the bounty until tomorrow. I will though!